# Offline Data sync with Enterprise Database using Firebase

Tags: ios, synchronization, firebase

I have a query regarding offline datasync with Enterprise database where Firebase acts as mediator.

My questions are

1. Does Firebase support to connect Enterprise database (say Oracle) and act as a mediator between mobile device & Enterprise database?
2. If Yes, does Firebase support for offline sync between mobile device & enterprise database.

For your reference, I found that Kony provide  same type [Offline Sync](http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/sync/kony_sync_developing_offline_applications/Default.htm#Generating_%20Offline_Service.htm#Introduc%3FTocPath%3DDeveloping%2520Offline%2520Applications%7C_____2) feature . I am looking for same feature with Firebase.

Any idea or suggestion would be great.

Thanks

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. If such things were features of Firebase, they'd be [documented](https://www.firebase.com/docs/). You can probably build a middle tier that does such synchronization, but Firebase doesn't include one.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That smells like an answer to me.

Comment: I would want to understand the scope of your project to determine if Firebase could be a mediator. You can certainly write code to make it behave in that fashion but more importantly, why not just use Firebase for your project instead of Oracle? It's designed to handle very large datasets with thousands of concurrent connections.

Answer (score 2):

There is no full solution implemented in Firebase. But Firebase does provide client offline support. From the [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html)

> Every client sharing a Firebase database maintains its own internal version of any active data. When data is updated or saved, it is written to this local version of the database. The Firebase client then synchronizes that data with the Firebase servers and with other clients on a 'best-effort' basis.
>
> As a result, all writes to the database will trigger local events immediately, before any data has even been written to the server. This means the app will remain responsive regardless of network latency or Internet connectivity.
>
> Once connectivity is reestablished, apps receive the appropriate set of events so that the client "catches up" with the current server state, without having to write any custom code.

Adding another tier (maybe a node.js server) could then monitor Firebase for any updates synced from the clients and move them to the main database